# Are compact complete geodesics closed?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

note: I find this question In stackexchange math, I would be interest to know how I could be answer this kind of question,I pasted it here  as I see it appropriate For MO.

check this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1030616/156150.

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold.

Is there an example of a geodesic $c:\mathbb{R}\to M$ s.t. $c(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, $c$ is NOT periodic (i.e. be NOT a closed geodesic) ?

I would be interest for any replies or any comments .Thank you

Comment: Please link to the original question.

Comment: The question on math.stackexchange already has an answer.  Why did you want to repeat the question here?

Comment: this question havn't answer for 3 days before , and  i pasted it here as i see it apprpriate for MO

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was asked and answered elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c:\mathbb R\to M$ be a unit speed geodesic. Then $c':\mathbb R\to UM:=\lbrace X\in TM: \|X\|=1\rbrace\subset TM$ is a flow line for the flow of the geodesic spray $S$. Since $UM$ is compact, flow-lines of $S$ are either periodic or non-compact. Thus the same is true for geodesics on $M$.